# symfony : form presetdata event not called

Tags: php, forms, symfony, event-listener

This issue is linked to the following post : [symfony2: presetdata event not working when form is a service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27610973/symfony2-presetdata-event-not-working-when-form-is-a-service)

It appears I can't use form event PRESETDATA on a form if the form is a service and called through ->add('field', 'my_service_form'). If instanciated with new FormType, this goes well.

Has someone already made form events work with forms declared as services?

**EDIT:
The form being a service or not does finally not seem to be the real issue.**

I have made a very simple case scenario to explain better the problem.
My home page controller is calling a form which is calling the subform fmu_sunit which is a service. Inside this service I am trying to add fields inside the presetdata_event. This is not working

My controller:

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use AppBundle\Entity\MarketPlace\Product;
use AppBundle\Form\UnitTestType;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Method;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="home")
     * @Method({"POST", "GET"})
     * @Template(":Default:index.html.twig")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $formManager = $this->get('form_manager');

        $product = new Product();
        $unit = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Unit')->findOneByName('g');
        $product->setUnit($unit);

        $form = $formManager->createForm(new UnitTestType(), $product ,'POST', 'home');

        return array('form' => $form->createView());
    }
}
```

My first Type (UnitTest):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UnitTestType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('unit', 'fmu_unit')
        ;
    }

    /**
     * @param OptionsResolverInterface $resolver
     */
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\MarketPlace\Product'
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'unit_test';
    }

}
```

My second type (the service one in which I try to use Form Events):

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class UnitType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function(FormEvent $event) {
                $product = $event->getData();
                $form = $event->getForm();

                //This is not working
                $form->add('unit','entity', array(
                        'class' => 'AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Unit'
                    ));
            });

        //This is working
//        $builder->add('unit','entity', array(
//                'class' => 'AppBundle:FoodAnalytics\Unit'
//            ));
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'inherit_data' => true,
            ));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'fmu_unit';
    }

}
```

The declaration as a service:

```
services:
    unit.type:
        class: %unit.type.class%
        tags:
            - { name: form.type, alias: fmu_unit }
```

The view :     {{ form(form) }}
Nothing shows up but the label when I use the form Events. It works fine if I don't use it.

EDIT2 : 
The code of the createForm from my FormManager service:

```
$form = $this->formFactory->create
(
    $type,
    $entity,
    array(
        'action' => $this->router->generate($route, $routeParameters),
        'method' => $method,
    )
);
```

Comment: Yes.  Events work fine even with a form service.  Try to narrow down your issue and post some code.

Comment: They work fine, there problem lies somewhere within your code

Comment: I have just added a simple non-working example. That would be great if you had time to look at it! Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the `form_manager` service, and where is it coming from?

Comment: the form manager service is just my custom service for creating forms. I have added an edit with the createForm code, just itself calling a formfactory